# Can you make flexbox background height the same?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using flexbox display and it is working fine. Except when I happen to use a background color on one of the divs, the color does not cover the entire height of the div. It ends up looking like this --

[image]

Of course what I'd like is for the background color to extend to the same height as the div to the right. Is this even possible with flexbox?

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.left {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    background-color: wheat;
}
.right {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="left">Some text</div>
    <div class="right">
        <input type="text" style="height:40px" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you use

```css
align-items: center;
```

The default value does what you want:

```css
align-items: stretch;
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.left {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background-color: wheat;
}
.right {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="left">
    Some text
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <input type="text" style="height:40px" />
  </div>
</div>
```

But then you will need to center the contents vertically. You can do it with more flexbox. Some examples:

- Row layout and `align-items`:

  ```css
  .left {
    display: flex;       /* More flexbox */
    align-items: center; /* Center in the cross (vertical) axis */
  }
  ```

  ```css
  .row {
    display: flex;
  }
  .left {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    background-color: wheat;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .right {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left">
      Some text
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <input type="text" style="height:40px" />
    </div>
  </div>
  ```
- Column layout and `justify-content`:

  ```css
  .left {
    display: flex;           /* More flexbox */
    flex-direction: column;  /* Column layout */
    justify-content: center; /* Center in the main (vertical) axis */
  }
  ```

  ```css
  .row {
    display: flex;
  }
  .left {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    background-color: wheat;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .right {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left">
      Some text
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <input type="text" style="height:40px" />
    </div>
  </div>
  ```
- Inserting pseudo-elements with `auto` margins:

  ```css
  .left {
    display: flex;          /* More flexbox */
    flex-direction: column; /* Column layout */
  }
  .left::before, .left::after {
    content: '';            /* Generate pseudo-elements */
    margin: auto;           /* Push contents */
  }
  ```

  ```css
  .row {
    display: flex;
  }
  .left {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    background-color: wheat;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .left::before, .left::after {
    content: '';
    margin: auto;
  }
  .right {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left">
      Some text
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <input type="text" style="height:40px" />
    </div>
  </div>
  ```